# Netty dynamic Channelhandler pipeline

Tags: java, netty

I am trying implement the Netty 4.X with dynamic ChannelHandler pipeline. 
As people suggested "Use invocation instead of pipeline modification at runtime for performance concern.", I implemented a Server, an RouterInboundHander and a Client to test this theory. but it doesn't work. Here is my Code

Server

```
import io.netty.bootstrap.ServerBootstrap;
import io.netty.channel.ChannelInitializer;
import io.netty.channel.ChannelOption;
import io.netty.channel.EventLoopGroup;
import io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup;
import io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketChannel;
import io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel;
import io.netty.handler.codec.DelimiterBasedFrameDecoder;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

public class Server implements Runnable{

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Server.class);
    public static final int PORT = 9528;
    public static final String TIME = "time";
    public static final String REVERSE = "reverse";
    public static final String ERROR = "error";


    @Override
    public void run() {

        final EventLoopGroup boss = new NioEventLoopGroup();
        final EventLoopGroup work = new NioEventLoopGroup();
        try {
            new ServerBootstrap()
                    .group(boss, work)
                    .channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class)
                    .option(ChannelOption.SO_BACKLOG, 128)
                    .childHandler(new ChannelInitializer<NioSocketChannel>() {
                        @Override
                        protected void initChannel(final NioSocketChannel ch) throws Exception {
                            ch.pipeline().addLast(new DelimiterBasedFrameDecoder(1024 * 1024, RouterInboundHandler.DELIMINATOR));
                            ch.pipeline().addLast(new RouterInboundHandler());
//                            ch.pipeline().addLast(new RouterInboundHandler.StringWriterOutboundHandler());
                        }
                    }).bind(PORT).sync().channel().closeFuture().sync();
        } catch (final Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            boss.shutdownGracefully();
            work.shutdownGracefully();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Thread(new Server()).start();
    }

}
```

RouterInboundHandler

```
import io.netty.buffer.ByteBuf;
import io.netty.buffer.Unpooled;
import io.netty.channel.*;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

import java.util.Date;

public class RouterInboundHandler extends SimpleChannelInboundHandler<ByteBuf> {

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(RouterInboundHandler.class);
    public static final ByteBuf DELIMINATOR = Unpooled.copiedBuffer("\r\n".getBytes());

    private final ChannelInboundHandler timer = new TimePrinterInboundHandler();
    private final ChannelInboundHandler string = new StringReverseHandler();
    private final ChannelInboundHandler error = new ErrorInboundHander();


    @Override
    public void channelActive(final ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Connection made");
    }

    @Override
    public void channelInactive(final ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("OOOPS");
    }

    @Override
    protected void channelRead0(final ChannelHandlerContext ctx, final ByteBuf msg) throws Exception {
        final byte[] data = new byte[msg.readableBytes()];
        msg.readBytes(data);
        final String command = new String(data);

        if (command.equals(Server.TIME)) {
            timer.channelRead(ctx, command);
        } else if (command.equals(Server.REVERSE)) {
            string.channelRead(ctx, command);
        } else {
            error.channelRead(ctx, command);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void exceptionCaught(final ChannelHandlerContext ctx, final Throwable cause) throws Exception {
        cause.printStackTrace();
        ctx.close();
    }

    public static final class StringWriterOutboundHandler extends ChannelOutboundHandlerAdapter {
        @Override
        public void write(final ChannelHandlerContext ctx,
                          final Object msg, final ChannelPromise promise) throws Exception {
            if (msg.getClass().equals(String.class)) {
                System.out.println("I am writing " +  msg + " to the client");
                ctx.writeAndFlush(Unpooled.copiedBuffer(((String) msg).getBytes()));
            } else {
                System.out.println("This is not supposed to be");
            }
        }
    }

    public static class TimePrinterInboundHandler extends SimpleChannelInboundHandler<String> {

        @Override
        protected void channelRead0(final ChannelHandlerContext ctx, final String msg) throws Exception {
            System.out.println("I received message " + msg);
            final String time = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()).toString();
            System.out.println("TimePrinterInboundHandler invoked");
            ctx.writeAndFlush(Unpooled.copiedBuffer((time + " @ " + msg).getBytes()));
        }
    }

    public static class StringReverseHandler extends SimpleChannelInboundHandler<String> {

        @Override
        protected void channelRead0(final ChannelHandlerContext ctx, final String msg) throws Exception {
            final byte[] data = msg.getBytes();
            final byte[] newData = new byte[data.length];
            for (int i = 1; i <= data.length; i++) {
                newData[data.length - i] = data[i - 1];
            }
            System.out.println("StringReverseHandler invoked");
            ctx.writeAndFlush(Unpooled.copiedBuffer(new String(newData).getBytes()));
        }
    }

    public static class ErrorInboundHander extends SimpleChannelInboundHandler<String> {

        @Override
        protected void channelRead0(final ChannelHandlerContext ctx,
                                    final String msg) throws Exception {
            System.out.println("ErrorInboundHandler invoked");
            ctx.writeAndFlush(Unpooled.copiedBuffer(("Error appears, here is what you gave me [" + msg + "]").getBytes()));
        }
    }

}
```

and the Client

```
import io.netty.bootstrap.Bootstrap;
import io.netty.buffer.ByteBuf;
import io.netty.buffer.Unpooled;
import io.netty.channel.*;
import io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup;
import io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel;

public class Client implements Runnable{

    private ChannelHandlerContext channelHandlerContext;

    @Override
    public void run() {

        final EventLoopGroup work = new NioEventLoopGroup();

        try {
            new Bootstrap()
                    .group(work)
                    .channel(NioSocketChannel.class)
                    .option(ChannelOption.SO_BACKLOG, 128)
                    .handler(new ChannelInitializer<NioSocketChannel>() {
                        @Override
                        protected void initChannel(final NioSocketChannel ch) throws Exception {
                            ch.pipeline().addLast(new ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter(){
                                @Override
                                public void channelActive(final ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
                                    Client.this.channelHandlerContext = ctx;
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void channelRead(final ChannelHandlerContext ctx, final Object msg) throws Exception {
                                    if(msg instanceof ByteBuf){
                                        final byte[] data = new byte[((ByteBuf) msg).readableBytes()];
                                        ((ByteBuf) msg).readBytes(data);
                                        System.out.println(new String(data));
                                    } else {
                                        System.out.println("No");
                                    }
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void channelReadComplete(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
                                    System.out.println("ChannelReadComplete in Client");
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Throwable cause) throws Exception {
                                    cause.printStackTrace();
                                    System.out.println("Here");
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }).connect("localhost", Server.PORT).sync().channel().closeFuture().sync();
        } catch (final Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            work.shutdownGracefully();
        }

    }

    public ChannelHandlerContext getChannelHandlerContext() {
        return channelHandlerContext;
    }

    public void writeMessage(final String... message){
        for(final String msg : message) {
            channelHandlerContext.write(Unpooled.copiedBuffer(msg.getBytes()));
            channelHandlerContext.write(RouterInboundHandler.DELIMINATOR);
        }
        channelHandlerContext.flush();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        final Client client = new Client();
        new Thread(client).start();
        Thread.sleep(2000);
//        client.writeMessage(Server.TIME, Server.REVERSE, "Hello World");
        client.writeMessage("Hello World", Server.TIME, Server.REVERSE);
    }

}
```

As shown in the code, Three sub-classes of ChannelInboundHandler are created during connection initialization phase of a Channel. When the client sends message to Server, the channelRead0 will check command and run different handler accordingly.

My problem is, if this is a correct way of using Netty pipeline dynamically?, and why only the first request from client is ever responded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without more information is hard to say what exactly you try to do but I suspect the problem is that the following code will try to write the same ByteBuf multiple times:

`channelHandlerContext.write(RouterInboundHandler.DELIMINATOR);`

This is problematic for multiple reasons:

1) Your will share the same reader / writerIndex which may be updated and so it may write different content
2) The ByteBuf will be released after written so you may get a IllegalReferenceCountException when you try to write it again.

You should see any write error reflected in the ChannelFuthre that is returned by the `write(...)`. Just add a `ChannelFutureListener` to it and check if the write failed or not.

So without any more informations I think you should do:

```
channelHandlerContext.write(RouterInboundHandler.DELIMINATOR.retainedDuplicate());
```

Comment: you have pinpoint the exact problem, the reason only one request was ever responded is DELIMINATOR was not retained. I have updated the code according to your answer. it worked. thanks